# how to send push notification when Azure blob create or update

Tags: azure, notifications, azure-blob-storage

I am new in Azure development. I managed to make an Azure blob and Notification Hub. I would like to send a push notification as soon as a blob is created. I have no idea how to do it. Could you please share some idea and links? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [**blob trigger**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger) in [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function) to do it,

> The Blob storage trigger starts a function when a new or updated blob is detected.

then set the [Notification Hubs output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs), when the function is triggered, it will send push notifications.

> This article explains how to send push notifications by using Azure Notification Hubs bindings in Azure Functions. Azure Functions supports output bindings for Notification Hubs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use an `eventgridtrigger` rather than a `blotrigger` when you use a storage account v2